# Calling function expression from external Javascript file within Angular4 component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I'm having hard times trying to call a **function expression** from an external **Javascript file** (called roadmap.js) within the web application I'm developping using **Angular4** and angular-cli. Roadmap.js is based on d3.js and available on a public Github repo.

For now, I have:

1. Installed d3 and @types/d3 via npm
2. Put roadmap.js file in my asset folder, after tweaking it to isolate a parse function
3. Imported d3 in roadmap.component.ts
4. Declared **parse**,  the function I'd like to call in my component, as an any var in top the ts file
5. Call the function within ngOnInit()

roadmap.component.ts

```
declare var parse: any;

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../../../services/data/data.service';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import '../../../../assets/js/roadmap.js';
@Component({
  selector: 'roadmap',
  templateUrl: './roadmap.component.html'
})

export class RoadmapComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private dataService: DataService){}
    ngOnInit() {
        new parse(); // Here is the function I'd like to call. It's defined 
                     // in roadmap.js file
    }
}
```

roadmap.js

```
// Code before this
var parse = function() {
    // Tasks
    var colors = d3.scale.category20();
    // More code 
};
// Code after this
```

I'm not receiving errors from the compiler but in my browser console I can read that the function **parse** is undefined --> 
Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: parse is not defined
ReferenceError: parse is not defined

So What did I miss? 
**N.B**: my modified version of roadmap.js was working on a classic html/js website, so the problem shouldn't come from that js file.

Comment: If you're going to use the `declare`, take out the import statement for that file and just include it with a <script> tag on the index

Comment: `import` is meant to be used with modules.  `roadmap.js` is not a module exporting things, it's a global function.

Comment: Thanks, it helped but the roadmap won't render, due to undefined functions @Mark I'm confused: how should I handle this Js files to call the functions within, without having to rewrite it in typescript directly in the component?

Comment: Did you @AlbanLePape did you try as @megg said. Import it using `<script>` in your `index.html` check if the roadmap.js has loaded by invoking `parse` in the browser console.